# Visualforce page title is not set

Tags: visualforce

The problem is pretty straightforward.
We are using page title attribute to set title for our vf community pages, like:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="MemberHouseholdCont" title="{! $Label.union_MyFamily_PageTitle }" standardStylesheets="false">
```

For majority of pages everything works fine, i.e. defined custom title is displayed in browser. But for some pages (like the one with posted page tag above) attribute is completely ignored, i.e. there is no  tag in the header of generated html markup, and default title is used (full url to the page).

I tried to compare pages structures, but so far I couldn't find the cause of such behaviour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check API version of your visualforce page. The documentation depicts below for `title` attribute

> In pages set to API 29.0 or lower, if the showHeader attribute of
>    is set to false, no  element is generated.

Your VF page showHeader attribute is set to false. This may be the cause.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) for your reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just to help the future visitors of this answer. If you have development mode enabled, you won't see the page title.

Answer (score 1):

There is one alternative to do this. (May be you already did this but I will add it here for other's reference)

You can create another VF page as container to this page and then call your pdf page inside container page using iFrame. That way you will be able to set the page title dynamically.

For example, see below vf page named myPDFContainer.vfp which calls myPDFPage inside iFrame. You can set the pageTitle based on your logic inside MyController class.

```
<apex:page title="{!pageTitle}" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="MyController">
    <apex:iframe src="/apex/myPDFPage?Id={!recordId}" id="theFrame"/>
    <script>document.getElementById('theFrame').height = window.innerHeight - 20;</script>
</apex:page>
```